# ROSRUN can't find EXECUTABLE

Tags: ros-kinetic, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am using kinetic and I am trying to run a simple publisher and subscriber.

the cmakelists.xml has the following code.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(mastering_ros_demo_pkg)

cmake_policy(SET CMP0046 OLD)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  actionlib
  actionlib_msgs
  roscpp
  std_msgs
)


include_directories(
 include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)



add_executable(demo_topic_publisher src/demo_topic_publisher.cpp) 
add_executable(demo_topic_subscriber src/demo_topic_subscriber.cpp)


add_dependencies(demo_topic_publisher ${mastering_ros_demo_pkg}_gencfg)
add_dependencies(demo_topic_subscriber ${mastering_ros_demo_pkg}_gencfg)


target_link_libraries(demo_topic_publisher ${catkin_LIBRARIES}) 
target_link_libraries(demo_topic_subscriber ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

after running rosrun i get the following error :

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named demo_topic_publisher below /home/xavier/catkin_ws/src/mastering_ros_demo_pkg
```

I did source the `setup.bash` after catkin_make but still the issue was not sovled.

Please help me out here.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283774/rosrun-can%27t-find-executable/) by [Prof. xavier](https://answers.ros.org/users/33886/prof.-xavier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2018-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If that is really your `CMakeLists.txt`, it would appear you are missing a call to `catkin_package(..)`.

See [wiki/catkin/CMakeLists.txt](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt) for an overview of the various parts and why and when they are needed. See [wiki/catkin/CMakeLists.txt - catkin_package()](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt#catkin_package.28.29) specifically.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Prof. xavier](https://answers.ros.org/users/33886/prof.-xavier/) on 2018-02-26**:
I added the catkin_package but I still the same issue

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-26**:
Please make sure to delete your `devel` and `build` folders, rebuild your workspace and then `source /home/xavier/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-26**:
Also: could you update your question text and *add* the new `CMakeLists.txt` (do not overwrite your previous one), so it shows *where* you added `catkin_package(..)`? Use the `edit` button/link for that.

**Comment by [Prof. xavier](https://answers.ros.org/users/33886/prof.-xavier/) on 2018-02-26**:
okay, thanks for helping I will try this and post if any issues come along.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-24**:
Did you resolve this issue? If so, please click on the checkmark next to the answer to mark the question as answered.

**Comment by [taxi711](https://answers.ros.org/users/37016/taxi711/) on 2018-08-16**:
thanks gvdhoom, fixed it for me

**Comment by [digitalhub](https://answers.ros.org/users/40435/digitalhub/) on 2019-03-11**:
type chmod +x "your programfile"
and you can confirm rosrunable file